# Firebase/Crashlytics does not show line number for crashes

Tags: xcode, crashlytics, crash-reports

In the Crashlytics page for my app, I'll select the details for a crash and the stack will show the following

```
MyAppNamne    -[Crashlytics crash] + 14

MyAppName     <compiler-generated> - Line 0
              ClassName.functionName()

ReactiveSwift $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GxyccfcyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA10Disposable_ptcfU_ + 72

...

MyAppName     AppDelegate.swift - Line 25
              main
```

What I find interesting is that the line number is revealed for AppDelegate function call but not for my other function call :/

I also thought that perhaps this was a reactive thing but I've called the crash function in functions like UIViewController.viewWillAppear with the same result here's what that call stack looks like

```
MyAppName  -[Crashlytics crash] + 14

MyAppName  <compiler-generated> - Line 0
           @objc SupportViewController.viewWillAppear(_:)
```

My app does seem to be uploading the DSYM properly as seen here in the build log

```
2018-12-14 12:02:38.950 upload-symbols[72895:5123369] Successfully submitted symbols for architecture arm64 with UUID 0c19fa376c7f364b82908b1d308c9b59 in dSYM: /path/myAppName.app.dSYM
Uploading dSYM /path/myAppName.app.dSYM
```

**Build settings**
For the 'Build Active Architecture Only' setting, I set a No for release

And I also put the following settings for strip symbols
[image]

It might be overkill at the moment, but I can reel it back in when I find out what's going on.

I don't know what more I can do to get the line number back for my crash reports.

Thank you.

Comment: are you able to resolve this

Comment: I have the same issue, for my release version, I have two project with different bundle.

Comment: I resolved this issue by adding the following command to a new "Run Script Build Phase": `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"`